# Как связать таблицы в одну?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть некоторая база. Я хочу соединить таблицы `aplication_stafss` и `possible_positions` в одно целое. Я пробовал через данный способ, но в результатах я не виже ничего из второй таблицы.

`ApplicationStaff.includes(:possible_positions).first`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как смотрите?

Comment: @D-side в смысле

Comment: *в результатах я не виже ничего*